# How "equals" in express-validator works?

Tags: express, validation, routes, express-validator

I have to validate two fields are equals. In this case both passwords are the same. The problem it is that the "equals" from express-validator is not working.

This is the code:

```
app.post('/register', [
 isNotLogged,
 check('email', 'The email must be a valid one').isEmail(),
 check('nickname', 'The nickname must be filled').notEmpty(),
 check('password', 'The password must contain minimum eight characters, at least one letter and one number')
    .matches("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,}$"),

 //This is not working
 check('passwordConfirm', 'The passwords must match').equals('password'),

 validateResults
], register)
```

Comment: Your code is comparing whatever value `passwordConfirm` field is set to to the string value `'password'`. Have you seen the [example here](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/blob/7f136ceec156450e7fbf2d63d87313a5025ca25f/website/versioned_docs/version-6.9.0/feature-running-imperatively.md#example-validating-with-a-condition)?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem like this:

code before:

```
const registrar = async (req, res) => {
 
  await check('password').isLength({ min:6}).withMessage('password short ').run(req);
  await check('repetir_password').equals('password').withMessage('password diferente?').run(req);
  let resultado = validationResult(req);
  res.json(resultado.array());

};
```

after:

correct code: change

> 'password'

by

> req.body.password

```
const registrar = async (req, res) => {

  await check('password').isLength({ min: 6 }).withMessage('password corta ').run(req);
  await check('repetir_password').equals(req.body.password).withMessage('password diferente?').run(req);
  let resultado = validationResult(req);

  res.json(resultado.array());

 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [Express-Validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/validation-chain#if) doesn't work with [Validator.js's](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js) `equals()`, you'll have to use one of [Express-Validator's](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/validation-chain#if) middlewares and not its [Validator.js](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js) affility.

Here is an example straight from [Express-Validator's](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/validation-chain#if) website which seems fit your use case:

```
  body('oldPassword')
  // if the new password is provided...
  .if((value, { req }) => req.body.newPassword)
  // OR
  .if(body('newPassword').exists())
  // ...then the old password must be too...
  .notEmpty()
  // ...and they must not be equal.
  .custom((value, { req }) => value !== req.body.newPassword);
```

You do not need to use [Express-Validator's](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/validation-chain#if) `check` middleware as you are throwing away your ability to utilise [Validator.js's](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js) validators. Instead of `check` you could use `isEmail()` and `exists()` (an [Express-Validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/validation-chain#if) validator). Also, you don't need to have your middlewares as part of an array (although you can):

```
app.post('/register',
    isNotLogged,
    body('email').isEmail().withMessage('The email must be a valid one').bail().trim(),
    body('nickname').exists({ checkNull: true }).withMessage('The nickname must be filled').bail().trim(),
    body('password').trim().if((value, { req }) => (typeof req.body.passwordConfirm !== 'undefined')).bail().custom((value, { req }) => value !== req.body.passwordConfirm).withMessage('The email must be a valid one').bail().trim().matches("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,}$"),
    validateResults,
    register
);
```

Here the `body()` function would come from `const { body } = require('express-validator')` theres a few others similar for query paramaters, header parameters ect, all are documented [here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html#bodyfields-message).

I also used some `trim()`s and `bails()`s just to be safe. You can read up on those [here](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#sanitizers) and [here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#bail).